# React/Enzyme Component functions are not updating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, enzyme

I have a component that works on localhost. If you input a letter of a champion, the onInputHandler(input) changes the state of the component into a valid champion's name. Unfortunately, when I am testing with enzyme, the state of a component never changes (stays default). I would be glad for any advice. When I set this.statechampionsList with an array, the result is the same. Normally the array is filled with getChampionsList() after componentDidMount().

```
        export class ChooseChampion extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            championSelected: "Choose champion",
            championsList: []
        };

        this.onInputHandler = this.onInputHandler.bind(this);
        this.getFilteredChampion = this.getFilteredChampion.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getChampionsList();
    }

    getChampionsList = () => {
        fetch('/champions-list')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(champions => this.setState({ championsList: champions }))
    }

    onInputHandler(event) {
        if (event.target.value === "") {
            this.setState({
                championSelected: "Choose champion"
            });
        } else {
            const input = event.currentTarget.value;
            const filteredChampion = this.getFilteredChampion(input)
            this.setState({
                championSelected: filteredChampion
            });
        }
    }

    getFilteredChampion(input) {
        let oneFilteredChampion = this.state.championsList.find(champion => champion.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()))
        if (oneFilteredChampion) {
            return oneFilteredChampion;
        } else {
            return "Wrong name!"
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="choose-champion-container">

                <div className="role-and-caption inactive">
                    <img className="role-icon" src={require(`../assets/images/${this.props.lane}_icon.png`)} alt={this.props.lane} />
                    <span className="role-caption">{this.props.lane}</span>
                </div>

                <div className="champion-avatar-and-caption">
                    <ChampionAvatar currentChampion={this.state.championSelected} championsList={this.state.championsList} />
                    <ChampionCaption currentChampion={this.state.championSelected} championsList={this.state.championsList} />
                </div>

                <div className="search-container">
                    <button type="submit" className="search-button"><img src={SearchIcon} className="search-icon" alt="Search" /></button>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Find champion..." name="search" onInput={this.onInputHandler} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    };
}
```

Here is my testing statement:

```
const lanes = ["Top", "Jungle", "Middle", "Bottom", "Support"]
const app = <ChooseChampion lane={lanes[Math.floor(Math.random() * (5))]} />;

it('Should change the state after change the input value', () => {
  const newValue = 'Ahri';
  const wrapper = mount(app);
  const input = wrapper.find('input');

  input.value = newValue;

  wrapper.update();
  expect(input.value).toEqual(newValue);
  expect(wrapper.state('championSelected')).toEqual(newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

`input.value = newValue;`

with

`input.simulate('change', {target: {value: newValue}});`

or

`input.simulate('input', {target: {value: newValue}});`

To actually trigger the event (`onChange` or `onInput`), you need to simulate the DOM event. Just changing the value in input does not trigger React listeners.

Another thing is you do a fetch in componentDidMount. That's an async call. Just after `mount` the list of champions won't be populated. There are a couple of ways to wait  until it is. You might use [wait-for-expect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-for-expect) or write a similar function yourself. So, finally the test should look similar to:

```js
it('Should change the state after change the input value', () => {
  const newValue = 'Ahri';
  const wrapper = mount(app);

  await waitForExpect(() => {
    expect(wrapper.state('championsList')).to.be.not.empty;
  });

  const input = wrapper.find('input');

  input.simulate('change', {target: {value: newValue}});

  wrapper.update();
  expect(input.value).toEqual(newValue);
  expect(wrapper.state('championSelected')).toEqual(newValue);
});
```

*Note*: you might prefer to use a tool like [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock/) to mock the backend instead of calling an actual endpoint in tests.

Comment: Witaj Krzysztofie,
thank you for your answer. I've thought the same but the simulation method doesn't even pass the test for most basic expectation, not to mention later triggered functions...In both cases (simulate change/input) the result is: 

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    Expected: "Ahri"
    Received: undefined

Comment: OK, now I noticed you do a `fetch` in `componentDidMount`. That's an async call. The state (list of champions) will update only once the promise is resolved. I'll update the answer with possible solution.